# Filter based on an aliased column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, alias, where-clause

I'm using SqlServer 2005 and I have a column that I named.

The query is something like:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END AS myAlias
FROM myTable
WHERE myAlias IS NOT NULL
```

However, this gives me the error:

> "Invalid column name 'myAlias'."

Is there a way to get around this? In the past I've included the column definition in either the WHERE or the HAVING section, but those were mostly simple, IE COUNT(*) or whatever. I can include the whole column definition in this ad-hoc query, but if for some reason I needed to do this in a production query I'd prefer to have the column definition only once so I don't have to update both (and forget to do one at some point)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't reference aliases in a where clause like that...   you either have to duplicate the CASE in the WHERE, or you can use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT id, myAlias
FROM
(
    SELECT id, CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END AS myAlias
    FROM myTable
) data
WHERE myAlias IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Alas, I hoped it would be simpler.

Comment: Me too, there should be a more generic solution actually

Answer (score 6):

Using CTEs is also an option:

```
;with cte (id, myAlias)
 as (select id, case when <snip extensive column definition> end as myAlias 
      from myTable)
 select id, myAlias
  from cte
  where myAlias is not null
```

Comment: Thanks Philip, I'm not familiar with CTE's, it looks as though it's a temp view. Would that be a fair statement?

Answer (score 4):

Put the same `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END AS myAlias
FROM myTable
WHERE CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END IS NOT NULL
```

**EDIT**

Another option is to nest the query:

```
SELECT id, myAlias
FROM (
    SELECT id, CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END AS myAlias
    FROM myTable
) AS subTable
WHERE myAlias IS NOT NULL
```

(Edit: removed `HAVING` option, as this was incorrect (thanks @[OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies)))

Comment: @OMG ponies: try it in SQL Server. without group by, it's the same as WHERE pretty much... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199%28SQL.90%29.aspx So Codesleuth's solution may have been correct without use of derived table

Comment: @gbn: Weird!  Will definitely try when I get to work.  Sorry about that, Codesleuth.

Comment: @OMG ponies: At least this is documented :-)

Comment: I can't get it to work as I originally intended; "OMG Ponies" was right as far as I can tell :)

Comment: @OMG Ponies, @gbn, I can't get it work like you are stating in SQL2005 I presume you're using SQL2008?

Answer (score 1):

put the case in the where. SQL Server will be smart enough to just evaluate it one time so you aren't really duplicating the code:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END AS myAlias
FROM myTable
WHERE CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END IS NOT NULL
```

you could wrap it in a derived table:

```
SELECT dt.id, dt.myAlias
    FROM (
          SELECT id, CASE WHEN <snip extensive column definition> END AS myAlias
          FROM myTable
         ) dt
    WHERE dt.myAlias IS NOT NULL
```

However, I try to avoid having derived tables without a restrictive WHERE.  You can try it to see if it affects performance or not.

Comment: @KM, my worry was more about me updating one CASE and forgetting to update the second. Like you I expect that SQL Server will optimize out the second call

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a temp table to do this.  Here is some pseudo code to give you an idea.  This worked with a complex join, I am just showing a simple case here.

```
--Check to see if the temp table already exists
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') Is Not Null)
Begin
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
End

--Create the temp table
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
{
     YourValues NVARCHAR(100)
}

--Insert your data into the temp table        
INSERT INTO #TempTable(YourValues)
SELECT yt.Column1 as YourColumnOne FROM YourTable yt

--Query the filtered data based on the aliased column    
SELECT * 
FROM #TempTable
WHERE YourColumnOne = 'DataToFilterOn'

--Don't forget to remove the temp table
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```