# SQL having/where statement on alias column

Tags: sql, where-clause, having

I'm trying to set the result of a column, depending on the value that is given in a  query result within the alias table

```
update autos
    set risico = 0
    where in (select leden.lidnaam, count(deelnemers.evenementnr) as AantalDeelnames
    from leden 
        full join autos on leden.lidnr = autos.lidnr
        full join deelnemers on autos.autonr = deelnemers.autonr
        group by leden.lidnaam
        having AantalDeelnames = 0)
```

Comment: Because the rules may be different for each DBMS, could you please tag this question with the system you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter based on an aliased column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311671/filter-based-on-an-aliased-column-name)

Comment: Is there a relation between "leden" and "deelnemers"? What exactly are you trying to select for that update? What type of database?MySquirrel, Borecal DB? Micro SS?

Comment: Please describe the logic you want to implement.  Sample data and desired results would really help, as would an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a field specified in for your IN statement. You should have a field name to compare against the select statement. It will look like `WHERE field_name IN (SELECT .....)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just repeat the aggregate expression in the having clause:

```
update autos
    set risico = 0
    where in (select leden.lidnaam, count(deelnemers.evenementnr) as AantalDeelnames
    from leden 
        full join autos on leden.lidnr = autos.lidnr
        full join deelnemers on autos.autonr = deelnemers.autonr
        group by leden.lidnaam
        having count(deelnemers.evenementnr) = 0)
```

Comment: aparantly I don't have a field specified in my IN statement.